# Ubuntu 17.10 does not display thumbnails for videos

Tags: 17.10, thumbnails

Though not a serious issue, it still bothers me. It displays thumbnails for images.
[image: Example]

I've also tried clearing thumbnails folder in `~/.cache/thumbnails`.

Comment: I've also tried clearing thumbnails folder in ~/.cache/thumbnails

Comment: Please don't add important info in comments, [edit] your question and add more details if needed.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Try installing `gstreamer1.0-libav` that should take care of most. The `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly` & `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` packages may be needed to get full coverage. You may need to remove the `~/.cache/thumbnails/fail` folder after installing.

Comment: Try installing ffmpegthumbnailer- `sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer`

Answer (score 2):

Install/Reinstall The Totem media player:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get purge totem`
`sudo apt-get install totem`

Clear the cache:

`rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails`

The install of totem (which totem-common package is a part of) creates the thumbnail configuration file:

`/usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer`

Comment: It didn't work. Totem was already installed. I still tried clearing the cache

Comment: @mohammedthahajk I updated my answer for reinstall.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thanks anyways.